# How can I create a game where you have to avoid circles with your mouse that move around randomly

Tags: processing

I don't know how to make the circles move. I also don't know how to make the game end when the mouse touches a circle.

I already have the circles drawn on screen

```
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
   int x = (int)random(100);
   int y = (int)random(100);
   ellipse(x,y,25,25);
}
```

It shows a screen with circles. I need them to move around and have the game end when the mouse touches them.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation) is a tutorial on animation (including how to move circles around) and [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection (including point-circle collision detection).

Answer (score -1):

In order to solve this problem you need to store the values of x and y in two arrays.

Next you need to initialize the arrays with a for loop (like your code).
In the order to have a continuous movement of the circle we add a little step each loop with another for loop.

And then you can calculate the distance between the mouse and each circle.

```
int[] x;//creation of arrays
int[] y;
int size = 30;
int nbBalls = 20;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400); 
  x = new int [nbBalls];
  y = new int [nbBalls];
  for(int i=0;i<nbBalls;i++){//initialisation
    x[i] = (int)random(400);
    y[i] = (int)random(400);
  }
}

void draw() 
{
  background(51);
  for(int i = 0; i < nbBalls; i ++)//draw
      ellipse(x[i],y[i],size,size);

  for(int i = 0; i < nbBalls; i ++) {//move
      x[i] = x[i] + (int)random(5)-2;
      y[i] = y[i] + (int)random(5)-2;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < nbBalls; i ++)//collision test
    if(dist(mouseX,mouseY,x[i],y[i])<size)
      noLoop();
}
```